# custom modals with vue js scrolling issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating bootstrap modals with vue js and i following [tutorial](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html) but with a few tweaks, and it works just fine but now when i have long modals i got some issue about scrolling page, since it is only scrolling page behind the modals but not the modals

here is my modal.vue component

```
<template>
    <div class="modal-mask" @click="close" v-show="created">
    <transition name="modal"
        enter-active-class="animated bounceInUp"
        leave-active-class="animated bounceOutDown"
        mode="out-in"
        v-on:enter="beforeEnter"
        v-on:after-leave="afterLeave"
    >
        <div class="modal-dialog" :class="size" v-if="show" @click.stop>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" :class="color">
                    <button type="button" class="close" @click="close">&times;</button>
                    <h6 class="modal-title">
                        <slot name="title"></slot>
                    </h6>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <slot name="button"></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </transition>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: ['show','color','size'],
    data(){
        return{
            created: false,
        }
    },
    mounted(){
      document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
          if (this.show && e.keyCode == 27) {
            this.close();
          }
      });    
    },
    methods: {
        close(){
            this.$emit('close');
        },
        beforeEnter(){
            this.created = true
        },
        afterLeave(){
            this.created = false
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
.modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
</style>
```

and to i just need to import this modal.vue component into any page that i needed.

so how to fix this scrolling issue?

Comment: Bootstrap modals set a class on the body as well, which sets a property of 'overflow: hidden` to prevent the body from scrolling while the modal is open. Have you tried doing something like that?

Comment: where do i need to put that overflow:hidden?

Comment: Like I said: "on the body". Your main body element of your HTML document.

Comment: oh but my main issue is not to prevent body from scrolling from modal is open, but to use scrolling in modal when modal is too long

Answer (score 1):

Well set css prop `overflow-y: auto` to your modal-body class

```
.modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have sth like this (where modal-wrapper is a div which wraps the elements inside modal-mask)

```
.modal-mask {
    z-index: 11010;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(44, 46, 47, 0.9);
}

.modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```